# Javascript iterating through sparse array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a sparse array (indexes are not consecutive) like this:

```
var testArray = { 0: "value1", 5: "value2", 10: "value3", 15: "value4" };
```

I would simply like to iterate through each item, do some stuff, and be able to break under a certain condition.

I am fairly new to Javascript and I didn't find a proper way to do it. Here is what I tried:

1. Built-in "for..in". It seems that this is [not the correct way to iterate through an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays)
2. [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) from ECMASCRIPT5. This one iterate correctly, but I cannot break from the loop.
3. [_.each()](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#each) from Underscore.js. Same result as #2.
4. [$.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) from JQuery. With this one I can break by returning false, but it won't iterate correctly. For the above example, instead of iterating at 0, 5, 10, 15, it will iterate at 0,1,2,3,4,5,6... which is obviously not what I expect.

So my question is: **Is there an easy way to iterate a sparse array with the possibility to break during the loop in Javascript or would it be better to use another data structure like an hashtable? If so, any recommandation?**

Thanks!

Comment: if you look through the link you provided in point #1, the built-in for..in loop IS the way to loop through an objects properties, which is what you have

Comment: From what I understood from the link was that a problem could potentially occur if a library add a member to the Array.prototype. Then the member will be part of the "for..in" loop.

Comment: Ah ok, my example wasn't valid as I was using an Object and not an Array. So your comment is correct.

Comment: The other SO page says "because you will get bit on the ass if somewhere else in your code exists a Array.Prototype.foo = 1".  Is that not valid here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What's wrong with the `for...in` syntax? You have an object so the `for...in` syntax is completely valid to use:

```
var testArray = { 0: "value1", 5: "value2", 10: "value3", 15: "value4" };

for (var key in testArray) {
  var value = testArray[key];

  if (...) {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I wanted to use a real Array instead of an Object? What would you use then?

Comment: @Absolom JS Arrays inherit from Object, so this will still work fine.

Comment: Does for..in guarantee order?

Comment: @Blender: How would you do it if you wanted to iterate in order? I'm missing a TreeMap in Javascript.

Comment: @JanusTroelsen: order isn't preserved when creating the object, so you can't.

Comment: @ScottBoring Yes it does: "The traversal order, as of modern ECMAScript specification, is well-defined and consistent across implementations. Within each component of the prototype chain, all non-negative integer keys (those that can be array indices) will be traversed first in ascending order by value, then other string keys in ascending chronological order of property creation." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Comment: @ScottBoring However, as I just discovered, it seems in practice to break after a certain point. I can't find any official mention of the maximum value, but it seems to break if you go higher than a billion or so and starts iterating out of order. It's likely implementation-specific.

Answer (score 3):

For..in isn't the worst thing when you're working on an object hash. It's to be avoided for use with arrays (`[]`), but it should be ok here:

```
var val;
for (index in testArray) {
  if (index == 10) {
    break;
  } else {
    val = testArray[index];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you have is not an array, it's just an object.

You can test by:

```
Array.isArray(testArray)
```

For what's worth, JavaScript does have array that's said to be sparse. This happens when you use `delete` operator to remove an element or change length property to larger.

To answer your question, to loop thru a object, best way is `Object.keys(obj).forEach()`.

```
var o = {"a":3, "b":4};

Object.keys(o).forEach(
    function (key) {
        var val = o[key];
        console.log("Key:" + key);
        console.log("Value:" + val);
    }
);
```

The possible issue with
`for (var p in o) {…}` is that it will also loop thru any enumerable properties in the parent (that is, the prototype chain). Usually it won't happen though, if you define you object by literal expression `var obj = {...}`, which by default its parent is Object.prototype, and it doesn't have any enumerable properties.

Answer (score 2):

First thing you have to kiss-bye-bye is "Array". There is no real `Array` in ECMAscript (forgetting about typed-arrays and binary trickery).

So what you've got there is a plain `Object`. To iterate over that, I'd suggest to use `.forEach` if you're cool with ES5. If you need to early break that iteration, you might want to use ES5 methods like `.some()` or `.every()`, like:

```
Object.keys( testArray ).some(function( key ) {
    if( +key < 15 ) {            
        return true;
    }

    console.log(key, testArray[key]);
});
```

This would interrup the iteration when a key is encountered which numerical value is not lower than 15, by returning `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use (abuse) `Array.every` instead of `Array.fromEach` to break out of the loop early.

```js
var pre = document.getElementById('console');

var arr = new Array();
arr[10] = 'Hello';
arr[20] = 'World!';
arr[30] = 'stop';
arr[40] = 'Goodbye';

arr.every(function (val, idx) {
  if (val !== 'stop') {
    pre.textContent += idx+': '+val+'\n';
    return true;
  }
});
```

```html
<pre id="console"></pre>
```

Basically, `Array.every` immediately returns `false` as soon as one of its elements returns `false`. This lets you break out of the loop early.