# Iterating over sparse arrays

Tags: javascript, sparse-matrix

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10569131/1737) says that the best way to iterate over sparse arrays is to use `for X in Array`

However, when I tried this I tripped up because the type of `X` was a string, rather than the integer index I was expecting. (All fine until I added it to another integer...)

```
var arr = [];
arr[10000] = "Hello";

var shifted = []

for (var x in arr)
    shifted[10+x] = arr[x];
```

"Expected":

```
  shifted[10010] = "Hello
```

Actual

```
  shifted["1010000"] = "Hello"
```

Is there a better way of iterating a sparse array using the index, or should I just use `Number(X)` where required?

Comment: In that post they are iterating objects, not arrays... Can you show an example of your array, and tell us what you actually want to do?

Comment: Internally, sparse `Array` keys are handled as `String`.

Comment: @Teemu - updated, sorry.

Comment: LOL, this has nothing to do with a sparse array. You're just concatenating a string to a number, and use that string as a new key. The teach of a lesson: [Never use](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea) `for..in` to iterate an array, use regular `for` loop or `for..each` or what ever else loop purposed to iterate arrays.

Comment: @Teemu, Well, if the array wasn't sparse I'd be using a vanilla for loop which avoids the problem. But for a sparse array that's not going to work. I'm more aware now of the `for in` pitfalls, and how to avoid them. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9329476/1737 . `.forEach` Looks the best approach, but I just need to remember that array keys are actually strings. Carve it on my tombstone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how V8 (and others JavaScript engines) handles arrays:

> V8 uses two different methods to handle arrays:
>
> - **Fast elements:**
>   Designed for arrays where set of keys are very compact. They have a **linear storage buffer** that can be accessed very efficiently.
> - **Dictionary elements:**
>   Designed for sparse arrays which don’t have every elements inside of them. It is actually a **hash table**, more expensive to access than “Fast Elements”
>
> **Source:** http://thibaultlaurens.github.io/javascript/2013/04/29/how-the-v8-engine-works/

When you are using a sparse array, the key is converted to string and then hashed. If you want numeric keys: don't use a sparse array or manually convert the key to a number.

Comment: Thanks. But if the array is not sparse, is the key still going to come back as a string in my `for X in Array`?

Comment: @Roddy No. When you use `for in` you are iterating through the object properties. A property is always a string. So even if your array is not sparse, `for in` will return strings.